# flutter серый экран в релизной версий на телефоне

Tags: flutter, экран

Приложение написано на **flutter** и работает нормально на android и виртуальных iphone, но когда готовое приложение устанавливаем на сам iphone, то появляется серый экран при попытке вставить логин или пароль.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может что-то не так с http запросами?

```
void send({
  Map<String, dynamic> body,
  String path = "",
  void Function(http.Response) onSuccess,
  void Function() onNetworkError,
  void Function(dynamic) onOtherError,
  void Function() onComplete,
  bool isPostMethod = false,
}) async {
  http.Response response;

  try {
    if (isPostMethod) {
      response = await http.post(
        Uri.http(address, initPath + path),
        body: body,
        headers: headers,
      );
    } else {
      response = await http.get(
        Uri.http(address, initPath + path, body),
        headers: headers,
      );
    }
    onSuccess?.call(response);
  } on SocketException {
    onNetworkError?.call();
  } catch (e) {
    onOtherError?.call(e);
  } finally {
    onComplete?.call();
  }
}

Future<void> removeAllCookies([bool isStoring = false]) async {
  headers["Cookie"] = "";
  if (isStoring) {
    var storage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    storage.setString("Cookie", headers["Cookie"]);
  }
}

Future<void> addCookie(String cookie, [bool isStoring = false]) async {
  headers["Cookie"] += cookie;
  if (isStoring) {
    var storage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    storage.setString("Cookie", headers["Cookie"]);
  }
}

Future<void> loadCookies() async {
  var storage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  headers["Cookie"] = storage.getString("Cookie") ?? "";
}
```

Comment: Похоже на какой-то оверлей, смотрите в ui что сверстали...

Answer (score 0):

Если не было прописано GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate раньше, то необходимо прописать. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13452